# Sharepoint 2010 calculate column default value

Tags: sharepoint, unique-key

I've created a column in Sharepoint called Key which will contain a unique value. What I want this unique value to be is the content of my 'Term' field minus the white-spaces using the Calculated Column functionality. So the Term Advanced Forward would have a Key value of AdvancedForward. Is it possible to do this? And if so, how can it be done?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Got it! Once I changed the column type to be a calculated column it was quite simple then:

```
 =REPLACE([Term],FIND(" ",[Term]),1,"")
```

Answer (score 0):

Alas the REPLACE function only replaces the FIRST find (starting at character 1 in your function) ([see Office Support: REPLACE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/REPLACE-function-2fc0760c-198a-49c1-ab93-329aa9f30e04?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US))

So "H e l l o W o r l d!"
with your function is reduced to: "He l l o W o r l d!"
(only the first space is replaced)

There is no SUBSTITUTE function in SharePoint, so the only way to get rid of multiple spaces is by nesting the REPLACE function.

So "H e l l o W o r l d!" can be reduced to "Hel l o Wo r l d!" (2 spaces replaced) with one function

```
REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
        Term
        ,FIND(" ",Term)
        ,1
        ,"")
    ,FIND(" ",REPLACE(
                    Term
                    ,FIND(" ",Term)
                    ,1
                    ,"")
        )
    ,1
    ,"")
```

For every extra space to be removed you have to replace all occurences of

```
Term
```

With

```
REPLACE(Term,FIND(" ",Term),1,"")
```

For 7 spaces you end up with a Formula 3688 characters long; as a calculated column can only be 4000 characters long; the only way to reduced more spaces is to continue with the outcome 
in another Calculated Column (chaining columns)